# Moment/Timezone - converting a date to unix

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, unix-timestamp

Why does the following return `Fri, 22 Apr 2016 13:01:00 GMT`?

Should it not be `Fri, 22 Apr 2016 17:01:00 GMT` (4 hours added for timezone)?

```
var zone = "America/New_York";
var date = 'Fri, 22 Apr 2016 13:01';
$('#ts').text(moment.tz(date, zone).unix()); // 1461330060
// epochconverter.com (1461330060) --> Fri, 22 Apr 2016 13:01:00 GMT ?!!
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/242/)

Edit: updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/243/). If I pass in `Fri, 22 Apr 2016 13:01` it now spits out `Fri, 22 Apr 2016 12:01:00 GMT`, so it ignores any DST as expected for UTC, but I'm still confused why it's not returning `Fri, 22 Apr 2016 17:01:00 GMT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was using jsfiddle which may be based in US, so moment was using localisation.

I did the following on my node server (based in London, UK) and the following code now works when I compare the results to [worldtimebuddy.com/est-to-utc-converter](http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/est-to-utc-converter):

```
var unix = moment.tz('2016-04-22T15:00', "America/New_York").unix();
var zulu = moment.utc(unix, 'X').format();
var local= new Date(zulu).toString();

console.log(unix); // 1461351600 (epochconverter.com --> Fri, 22 Apr 2016 19:00:00 GMT)
console.log(zulu); // 2016-04-22T19:00:00Z
console.log(local); // Fri Apr 22 2016 20:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

Summary, the times are now correctly converted:

- New York = 15:00
- Zulu/UTC = 19:00
- UK (DST) = 20:00

Comment: If i have a date like YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s can i convert it to unix using moment?